# Camel unit test - how can we write a unit test to assert that a particular method of a bean is invoked?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

In Camel, by using camel-test and Mock Endpoints, I don't know how can we assert that a Processor or a particular method of a Bean has been invoked?

For example, assume that I have a bean ProductService with several methods to get list of products or to update an existing product, here is the code to call a service method within the route:

```
from(endpoint)
   .bean(productService, "getAllProducts")
```

How can I assert that the method getAllProducts of the productService has been invoked?

My current approach is to use the thenAnswer to call a method that sets a flag to note that the method has been invoked. But I wonder that this is not a good approach:

```
boolean methodIsInvoked = false;

public void setMethodInvocation(){
     methodIsInvoked = true;
}

when(productService.getAllProducts(any())).thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocation -> {
       setMethodInvocation();
       return listOfProducts;
});

template.sendBody(...)

assertTrue(methodIsInvoked)
```

Comment: Mocking the productService itself in your spring context would be an option for you? If so - when using mockito for example you could assert it like this `verify(mockedProductService, times(1)).getAllProducts();`.

Comment: excellent it works, thanks. Why don't you put this as an Answer then I can mark it as Accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a mocking framework like mockito you could mock the ProductService in your spring test context:

```
@Bean
public ProductService mockedProductService() {
    return Mockito.mock(ProductService.class);
}
```

And in your test class assert your expected amount of invocations like this:

```
verify(mockedProductService, times(1)).getAllProducts();
```